# Responsive framework - edit child js

Tags: jquery, responsive

Is the [responsive framework](http://line25.com/articles/which-responsive-frameworks-are-designers-using) used by WordPress custom to WordPress, or is it a standard design? Where is the js file located that controls behaviour of the grid system used by theme twentytwelve? Is it the same file for all themes?

Comment: I don't think twentytwelve uses JS for its "grid system", only media queries.

Comment: I can confirm that @TheDeadMedic. As far as I know, none of the default themes uses above mentioned techniques, only media queries

Comment: OK - many thanks - this is a whole new world to me!!